# How to Document following function in JSDoc JS-Toolkit

Tags: jsdoc

**How to Document following function in JSDoc JS-Toolkit **

I want to document **try** and **help** method in this **main** function
but i did not figure it out how to do that.

```
/** Sample doc
* @class
* @constructor
* @name Sample
*/
var main=function(){
  this.value="";

  /** help function
  * @param {String} Name
  */
  this.help=function(name){
     console.log('help me'+name);
  }

  /** help function
  * @param {String} Name
  */
  this.try=function(name){
     console.log('try me'+name);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with this for several hours.  I tried:

- `@member`
- `@augments`
- `@method`
- `@this`

From the examples and tutorials I found, member functions and variables *should* appear in the output simply by having `/** description/*` comments above them, but I found that was not the case.  Like you, I'm using standard JavaScript constructors, where `this` should be able to be inferred automatically due to the `@constructor` being in place.  Maybe there's some wrinkle I'm not seeing.

In the end, I found two tags that worked for me, [`@name`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-name.html) and[`@memberof`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html).  They both allow you to specify the object that the property is a member of.  Using `@name` in this way is undocumented (at least, I didn't see it anywhere), but very straightforward.  You'll also need to use `@function`.

Here's an example with the `@name` tag:

```
/** help function
* @name Sample.try
* @function
* @param {String} Name
*/
this.try=function(name){
    console.log('try me'+name);
};
```

[image]

And here's an example with the `@memberof` tag:

```
/** help function
* @memberof Sample
* @function
* @param {String} Name
*/
this.try=function(name){
    console.log('try me'+name);
};
```

[image]

As you can see the output is almost the same.  The only difference that I see is that `@memberof` includes `this.` in the method name.  For that reason I've settled on using `@name`.

The remaining issue is that the functions are per-instance, not `<static>`.

Hope this helps!